# Login loses the question page

Tags: bug, questions, stackexchange, user-accounts, user-interface

Here on [Unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com), login is not as smooth as on other sites on the [Stack Exchange network](http://www.stackexchange.com).

I was on this question page : 
*[unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/where-did-the-wheel-group-get-its-name](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/where-did-the-wheel-group-get-its-name)*.

I was there as guest.

I clicked on “log in”.

First glitch : I had to enter my e-mail address and my password. Usually, they are shared from other Stack Exchange sites. But this is not a big deal.

**I logged in successfully, and I landed on the Unix home page : *[unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com)*. The site had lost the question. This is a bug.**

Usually, on other Stack Exchange sites, login keeps the question page — which is the expected behaviour.

Thank you for fixing this, and keep up the good work !

Comment: I'm not sure what you did, but all the SE sites run the same code, so I don't think there's a Unix-specific bug to fix

Answer (score 3):

I think you just didn't wait long enough. In general when I go to a SE site where I'm not logged in but have an account, when I go to the login page and click on the box to input my openid login if I reload that page or if I wait a bit it will detect me and auto log me in.

It isn't 100% rock solid across all the various SE properties but in general works I'd say 9 out of 10 times.